# Define a parametrization of the curve $C$

Tags: parametric, curves

> Consider the curve $C\in\mathbb R^3$ defined in Cartesian coordinates, by the equations
>   $$x=\sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}\qquad y=z+1$$
>   from $P_0=(\sqrt3,1,0)$ to $P_1=\left(\frac{\sqrt6}2,\frac32,\frac12\right)$. Define a parametrization of the curve $C$.

My answer was
$$(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{4-(t+1)^2-t^2},t+1,t)\qquad t\in\mathbb R$$
However the solution is $t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, which I can't understand why…

Comment: Use dollar signs to delineate MathJax here: `$x^2$` gives $x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't taken into account $C$'s endpoints. With the formula you found, you must now find $t$ such that $C(t)$ gives $P_0$ and $P_1$, and those values will be the bounds on $t$ for $C$. In this case, looking at $z$ immediately gives us the correct bounds of $\left[0,\frac12\right]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!